# Injecting $resource into controllers

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to make a module that returns a $resource object and I want to inject that $resource object into my other controllers. Here's my code

This is the module that returns a $resource ....

```
// module with resource
var rest = angular.module('rest', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource'])
.factory('profileAPI', function($resource) {

    // get the user id
$scope.userid = sessionStorage["cerestiuserid"];

// json we get from server
$scope.apicall = sessionStorage["cerestihome"];   

    return $resource($scope.apicall + "/api/userprofile/", {Userid:$scope.userid}, {'post':{method: 'POST'}});      
});
```

And these are the controllers I want to inject it in ...

```
var profile = angular.module('profile', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource', 'rest']);

profile.controller("profileController", ["$scope", "$resource", 'rest', function($scope, $resource, rest) { 

var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])

route.controller('editController', ["$scope", "$resource", 'rest', function($scope, $resource, infos) {
```

I'm injecting 'rest' into the controllers but it's giving me an error that says "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/unpr?p0=restProvider%20%3C-%20rest
    at Error (native)". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// injecting 'rest' module 
var profile = angular.module('profile', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource', 'rest']); 

//injecting profileAPI factory
profile.controller("profileController", ["$scope", "$resource", 'profileAPI', 
    function($scope, $resource, profileAPI) { ...

//injecting 'rest' module 
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router",'ngResource','route']) 

//injecting factory
route.controller('editController', ["$scope", "$resource", 'infos','profileAPI', 
    function($scope, $resource, infos,profileAPI) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes a lot more sense to inject profileAPI then route

Comment: If this solves your problem, you gotta make it as an answer so other users can refer to it as an answer.